# Spring Statemachine persistence

Tags: spring-statemachine

I am testing Spring Statemachine and in particular I am interesting in applying the statemachine to manage the state of my objects.

My Statemachine is of type `StateMachine<EpisodeState, EpisodeEvent>`.

My business object, `Episode`, has an enum property (`state`) of type `EpisodeState`, which should hold the statemachine state of the episode.  I have a batch process that will obtain an instance of Statemachine at initialization.  I would like to follow the basic flow:

- Load an `Episode` from the database
- Set the current state of the Statemachine from the `EpisodeState` that is in that `Episode` instance.
- Send an event to the Statemachine.
- Get the resultant state from the Statemachine (post event) and set the `EpisodeState` in my `Episode` instance.
- Save the `Episode` instance.

The documentation mentions an `extendedState` property, which in my tests is empty, but seems to support a map of arbitrary objects which I suppose I could use to hold the primary key of my `Episode`, but I am at a loss as to how to set the current state of the statemachine to the `EpisodeState` value in the `Episode`.

I have configured the statemachine with a `StateMachineInterceptorAdapter<EpisodeState, EpisodeEvent>`, and I can see the information at pre/post stateChange and at pre/post Transition, as well as the `preEvent`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further research (not in Spring Statemachine docs), I found a way to set the state of the statemachine:

Assuming you have the desired beginning state in a variable called `startingState`, you would do it like this:

```
stateMachine.stop();
stateMachine
    .getStateMachineAccessor()
    .doWithAllRegions(access ->
        access.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(startingState, null, null, null)));
stateMachine.start();
```